# c++ identical element removal from two arrays which do not contain the number itself in

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, set

Problem Statement: There are two arrays. Some elements are common on those arrays. Like arr1={5,2,6}; and arr2= {7,9,5,2,3}. Therefore, 5,2 are common elements because they exist on both arrays. As per the question I need to eliminate common elements from arrays. So the resulting arrays contain arr1={5} and arr2={7,9,3}.

My approach is first to merge both arrays within a third array and then eliminate duplicate elements using set operation. But in this approach, the element that appears 2nd time is deleted but the element itself in the list. Also, I get one list instead of two separate lists.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> remove_duplicate;
    int arr[3]={5,2,6};
    int arr1[5]={7,9,5,2,3};
    int m= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int n= sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int mergearr[m+n];
    std::copy(arr,arr+m,mergearr);
    std::copy(arr1,arr1+n,mergearr+m);
  for(int i=0;i<(m+n);i++){
  std::cout<<mergearr[i]<< ' ';
  }
  std::cout<< '\n';


 for(int j=0;j<(m+n);j++){
  remove_duplicate.insert(mergearr[j]);
 }
 for(auto it=remove_duplicate.begin();it!=remove_duplicate.end();++it){

  std::cout<<' '<<*it;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 2 6 7 9 5 2 3 
  3 9 7 6 2 5
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *How can I solve this problem?* -- Use `std::set_intersection` after sorting both arrays.  Second, `int mergearr[m+n];` -- you need to make `m` and `n` as `const int`, otherwise that declaration is not valid C++.

Comment: Also, you cannot remove elements from an array, since an array size is fixed.

Comment: Also, why is the answer for `arr` equal to `5`?  Shouldn't it be `6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, arrays are fixed in size, so erasing an element from an array is not possible, unless you define what is meant by "erasing from an array".  Thus the more appropriate container to use is `std::vector<int>`.

Given that, if you are allowed to sort both sequences, you can use [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) to first find the common elements.  Then use `std::remove_if` on both vectors using the generated set of common elements.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {5,2,6};
    std::vector<int> arr1 = {7,9,5,2,3};

    // First, sort both containers
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());

    // Next, call std::set_intersection to collect the common elements into 
    // the unordered_set
    std::unordered_set<int> common;
    std::set_intersection(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), 
                          std::inserter(common, common.begin()));

    // Now erase the items in each vector that matches the items in the set
    arr.erase(std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
                             [&](int n) { return common.count(n); }), arr.end());
    arr1.erase(std::remove_if(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), 
                             [&](int n) { return common.count(n); }), arr1.end());

    // Output results
    for (auto i : arr)
       std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto i : arr1)
       std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
6 
3 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

As PaulMcKenzie's comment says, you are looking to delete all items in the set intersection of the lists. Either use std::set_intersection or iterate through elements in the second array and check if they are in the first (using a set).